# Returning results from executor to driver

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark application, which basically takes in a big dataset, performs some computations over it, and finally does some IO to store it in a database. All of these stages happen on executors, and driver gets (collects) a boolean from each task, representing the success/failure status of that task (e.g. computation or IO may fail for some items).

E.g., following is an over-simplified lineage (in the actual implementation, there are multiple repartitioning and computation steps):

```
readSomeDataset()
  .repartition()
  .mapPartition { // do some calculation }
  .mapPartition { // do some IO }
  .collect()
```

**Problem:**
Based on the result of the computations, I would like to do something else on the driver (like publishing a message saying "computation was success"). This needs to be done once for the entire dataset, and not for individual partition, and thus needs to happen on the driver.

However, the IO on executors takes a long time, and I do not want to wait for that to finish before publishing.

Is there a way for the executors to send a 'message' back to the driver while in middle of processing the tasks?

(Something like Accumulators comes to mind, however, afaik they will be usable only once the final action finishes on the executors)

Comment: Scala , python or java?

Comment: I am using scala. However, with this really differ between the languages?

Answer (score 0):

Spark is a lazy framework, and need a complete job (from reading to writing) to execute, it can't execute only part.

To do these changes without reprocessing, you can cache dataframes, to recover as fast as you can, something like this.

```
val calculatedDF = readSomeDataset()
  .repartition()
  .mapPartition { // do some calculation }
  .cache() // or persist if can't fit in memory of the executors

if (caculatedDF.map(checkEackAreOK).reduce(_ && _).head) { // a condition to see if the calculations are ok and an action to launch it
  println("correct calculation")
  calculatedDF
    .mapPartition { // do some IO }
    .collect()
} else {
  println("incorrect calculation")
}
```

Comment: Yea, that is a possibility. I was trying to avoid caching, as that too has some overhead in terms of time, and also executor memory.